# calling jQuery method from HTML file not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to call a method in jQuery when a button is clicked in the HTML file. But I am unable to call the method. Please help me regarding this. 
Please let me know what wrong in my code.

my html file is

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Similar Entity Search-DFS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery   -1.10.0.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="newJs.js" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class ="filter" id="search-panel">
            <div class="search" id="search-box">
                                 <label>Enter Entity tuple</label>
                <button type="button"  class="btn-primary" id="search-button" >Search</button>
            </div>

        </div>


    </body>
 </html>
```

---

this html file calls the javascript file newJs.js which has jQuery

### This is my javascript file

```
 $(function(){

                page.init();

        });

        var page = {
            addEvent:function(){
                alert("here");
                   page.controls.searchButton.click(page.handlers.onSearchButtonClick);

            },

            handlers:{

                onSearchButtonClick: function(){

                alert("hi");
            },
            controls:{
            }

        },
    init: function(){

        page.controls.searchBox = $('#search-box');
        page.controls.searchPanel = $('#search-panel');     
        page.controls.searchButton = $('#search-button');
        page.addEvent();
    }
}
```

I am unable to print the alert message present in the search button method.
Please let me know the correction I should make in these code.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library url is malformed it should be: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js

This is why the first error was that `$` is not defined.

You can see the corrected version in this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/odozey/1/edit

Moreover in your example `controls` is a child of `handlers`, therefore the `init` function failed as well, because it was looking up `page.controls`.

So in the DEMO above I've modified it to be the child of `page`. And as you can see it works.

Comment: Thank you very much. Its solved my problem. But please let me know what is the best IDE to practice working in javscript, html and jquery stuffs. Because I am difficult to debug the problem since I am unable to see errors. Presently I am using notepad ++ and run on mozilla firefox. Once again thank you very much for solving this issue.

Comment: Basically `$(document).ready(function(){..});` / `$(function(){..});` / `$(document).on('ready', function(){..});` are equivalent. You can read more at http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: If you are using a later version of firefox: Press `Ctrl+Shift+K` to bring up the console (to see error messages) or use the debugger ( `Ctrl+Shift+S`). Or you might want to install firebug to go after clientside bugs

Comment: Hey thank you very much. Now I need a help. Now I need to deploy this application in server. So I used this but the ajax cannot call the servlet specified in the URL. So I thought that the ajax cannot able to map the servlet URL to servlet class. So how I can achive this and make the ajax cal my servlet on server. Please let me know if you know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You should put proper link to jquery library then it's just about ready action for document and click action for button

```
$(function (){
  $("#search-button").click(function (){
    alert("clicked"); return false;
  })
});
```

There is no need to write so complicated code if it can be coded so easily.

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your response. I wrote similar code as you gave it worked but when I used this code it does not.  I can not change the code because I need to use that code to integrate my other code. So I should use the same format of that code.

Answer (score 0):

`addEvent` is not a jQuery method: it's a different approach to event handling. If you're using jQuery use something like

```
$('#search-button').on('click', function() {
   // Do your searching stuff here
   alert("Searching!")});
```

Alternatively, you can get an 'addEvent' implementation [here](http://dean.edwards.name/weblog/2005/10/add-event/)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I don't have flexibility to change the code. I need to work on same code.